# Hibernate (4.2.7): Understanding of CascadeType PERSIST

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using **cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST** in my class that corresponds to a child table (PAT) as given below.

```
...
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Neighbourhood nh;
...
```

Neighbourhood class represents the parent table (NH).

[image: Here is the database relationship:]

**SQL generated:**

```
Hibernate: select neighbourh_.CODE, neighbourh_.NAME as NAME2_0_ from NH neighbourh_ where neighbourh_.CODE=?
Hibernate: insert into PAT (DOB, DOOR_NUM, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, HEIGHT, IS_MALE, LAST_NAME, LINE1, LINE2, MOBILE, nh_CODE, PHONE_HOME, PHONE_OFFICE, POSTAL_CODE, WEB, WEIGHT, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Issue**

When I try to save a record into the Child table (PAT), entry into the parent table (NH) is NOT created.  I want an entry to be created in the parent table as well as the child table.

Is this not what CascadeType.PERSIST supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what persist is supposed to do. Given only the details above I cannot say for sure why it is not inserted, but I can guess:

your `Neighborhood` entity has a PrimaryKey `code` that already exists in DB, when you insert it with the child table (Pat). That's why it looks for it within the first query. So if the Neighborhood code wasn't there, it would make an SQL insert for it.

Comment: NH table (Neighbourhood entity) is empty, I've confirmed this.  By the way, ALL instead of PERSIST inserts records in both the tables as expected, but I still have this issue with PERSIST.

Comment: Are you sure the entry is not saved a bit earlier? When the PAT entry is inserted, what is the NH's code of the inserted PAR row?